# Why there is no JDBC Spark Streaming receiver?

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, spark-streaming

I suggest it's a good idea to process huge JDBC table by reading rows by batches and processing them with Spark Streaming. This approach doesn't require reading all rows into memory. I suppose no monitoring of new rows in the table, but just reading the table once.

I was surprised that there is no JDBC Spark Streaming receiver implementation. Implementing [Receiver](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-custom-receivers.html) doesn't look difficult.

Could you describe why such receiver doesn't exist (is this approach a bad idea?) or provide links to implementations.

I've found [Stratio/datasource-receiver](https://github.com/Stratio/datasource-receiver). But it reads all data in a DataFrame before processing by Spark Streaming.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all actual *streaming* source would require a reliable mechanism for monitoring updates, which is simply not a part of JDBC interface nor it is a standardized (if at all) feature of major RDBMs, not to mention other platforms, which can be accessed through JDBC. It means that streaming from a source like this typically requires using log replication or similar facilities and is highly resource dependent.

At the same what you describe

> suggest it's a good idea to process huge JDBC table by reading rows by batches and processing them with Spark Streaming. This approach doesn't require reading all rows into memory. I suppose no monitoring of new rows in the table, but just reading the table once

is really not an use case for streaming. Streaming deals with infinite streams of data, while you ask is simply as scenario for [partitioning](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bapache-spark%5D+jdbc+partitioning) and such capabilities are already a part of the standard JDBC connector (either by range or by predicate).

Additionally receiver based solutions simply don't scale well and effectively model a sequential process. As a result their applications are fairly limited, and wouldn't be even less appealing if data was bounded (if you're going to read finite data sequentially on a single node, there is no value in adding Spark to the equation).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is a bad idea since in some cases you have constraints that are outside your power,e.g. legacy systems to which you cannot apply strategies such as CDC but to which you still have to consume as a source of stream data.

On the other hand, Spark Structure Streaming engine, in micro-batch mode, requires the definition of an offset than can be advanced, as you can see [in this class](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/MicroBatchExecution.scala#L384). So, if your table has some column that can be used as an offset, you can definitely stream from it, although RDMDS are not the "streaming-friendly" as far as I know.

I have developed [Jdbc2s](https://github.com/AbsaOSS/Jdbc2S) which is a DataSource V1 streaming source for Spark. It's also deployed to Maven Central, if you need. Coordinates are in the documentation.